# SQL Complex queries solved using SPARK-DATAFRAME/SQL

Tags: mysql, apache-spark-sql

I request you all to please post some of the complex SQL queries. And its best solution solved using spark-dataframes or spark-sql.

For Example.

> 1. Selecting department wise highest salary.
>
> Solution : Considering dataframe structure as Employee(id, name,
>   salary, departmentId)
>
> `employeeDF.max("salary").groupBy("departmentId").show()`

This will help us to understand how to write complex queries using dataframe.
And it is also helpful from interview perspective.

Thanks all in advance.

Few examples could be :

1. Select the nth highest salary.
2. Select the nth highest salary department wise.

Comment: Sorry but why does this read like a programming test question instead of a problem with programming?

Comment: Hi, this is a good idea, yet if might not be the place for it. good luck